# Is anybody moderating documentation and where can I see flags that I flagged in it?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-proposals

I am wondering if anybody is moderating documentation? I have flagged several examples, topics and so on, but I don't see any action being done. When I go to my flag-summary page I only see flags on posts I've made on SO, not on the documentation.

Is there a separate place where we can see the documentation flags?

Also can we have a documentation tag flag?

Currently there is a [wordpress-theming](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress-theming/topics) tag, which is empty, and can be safely put inside the WordPress tag that exists and has a lot of examples.

I get that creating a theme in WordPress is a big thing, but one could put all the details inside the WordPress tag (creating a theme for WordPress is still a WordPress thing). Or maybe we should have subtags, where we have tag parents and children? This would group some tags and clean things a bit.

I have flagged the two empty topics in that tag, but really I would like to flag the entire tag.

Comment: I know I was confused about this, but flags aren't really flags on Documentation, they turn into improvement requests and are made public: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/5571 . Stack Overflow moderators don't see these, but I think employees might have a listing of them that they review. My impression is that the idea is for the community to try to handle these, rather than any moderators.

Comment: So this basically means that anybody can create any kind of tag, without it being removed if it's kinda garbage? That's not really a great idea :\